# VueJS - Data and Method Scopes

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a Laravel Application and I'm routing through it to dynamically switch between Vue Components. For example:

**Laravel Blade View 1 (template.blade.php)**

```
...
<component is="@yield('vue')">
    @yield('content')
</component>
...
```

**Laravel Blade View 2**

```
@extends('template')

@section('vue', 'form-view');

@section('content')
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
@stop
```

**Vue Instance**

```
import FormView from 'FormView';

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        FormView,
    },
});
```

**FormView.js**

```
export default {
    methods: {
        submitForm() {
            alert('hello');
        },
    },
};
```

The issue is that I get the following message in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: v-on:submit="submitForm" expects a function value, got undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the HTML in the view is **not** a Vue Template it is considered as inline and needs to be defined as an inline template:

```
...
<component is="@yield('vue')" inline-template>
    @yield('content')
</component>
...
```